# InterruptedException not caught on RxJava onError callback?

Tags: java, exception, kotlin, rx-java2, thread-sleep

I have a simple code below

```
    compositeDisposable.add(Observable.create<Int> { Thread.sleep(1000) }
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe({}, {Log.d("Track", it.localizedMessage)}, {}))
    Handler().postDelayed({compositeDisposable.clear()}, 100)
```

It purposely use `Thread.sleep(1000)`, just to trigger the `InterruptedException`. I purposely delay 100 milliseconds, so that ensure the sleep in the chain has started, and dispose it.

(Note, I know using of `Thread.sleep` is not preferred. I'm just writing this code to test and understand why `onError` is not called on this scenario, and how to prevent the crash elegantly without need to use try-catch in the RxJava chain)

At that time, when it is triggered, the error is not cause `onError` (i.e. doesn't reach the `Log`. But instead it throws the below error and crash the App.

```
io.reactivex.exceptions.UndeliverableException: java.lang.InterruptedException
    at io.reactivex.plugins.RxJavaPlugins.onError(RxJavaPlugins.java:366)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableCreate$CreateEmitter.onError(ObservableCreate.java:74)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableCreate.subscribeActual(ObservableCreate.java:43)
    at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:11194)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableSubscribeOn$SubscribeTask.run(ObservableSubscribeOn.java:96)
    at io.reactivex.Scheduler$DisposeTask.run(Scheduler.java:463)
    at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.run(ScheduledRunnable.java:66)
    at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.call(ScheduledRunnable.java:57)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
 Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Thread.java:373)
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Thread.java:314)
    at com.elyeproj.porterduff.AnimateDrawPorterDuffView$startAnimate$1.subscribe(AnimateDrawPorterDuffView.kt:45)
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableCreate.subscribeActual(ObservableCreate.java:40)
    at io.reactivex.Observable.subscribe(Observable.java:11194) 
    at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableSubscribeOn$SubscribeTask.run(ObservableSubscribeOn.java:96) 
    at io.reactivex.Scheduler$DisposeTask.run(Scheduler.java:463) 
    at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.run(ScheduledRunnable.java:66) 
    at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.call(ScheduledRunnable.java:57) 
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Why was't the `InterruptedException` caught by the `onError` in RxJava?

Comment: Suggested reading: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0#error-handling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per pointed by @akarnokd, in https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0#error-handling, looks like the RxJava has been disposed before the throw, hence the error thrown later got through. To address the issue just need to register

```
 RxJavaPlugins.setErrorHandler { e -> /*Do whatever we need with the error*/ }
```