# How to catch the crash error of a onNext phase result of an rx-chain?

Tags: android, rx-java2

When I have the below flow, where the crash will happen in `doSomethingThatWillCrash()`, I was showing that it will be caught in `{ error -> showError(error.message }`, but it doesn't as it is already at subscribe onNext phase

```
    disposable = apiRepository.fetch()
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(
            { result -> doSomethingThatWillCrash() },
            { error -> showError(error.message }
        )
```

How could I handle the error?

I can do

```
try {
    disposable = apiRepository.fetch()
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(
            { result -> doSomethingThatWillCrash() },
            { error -> showError(error.message }
        )
} catch(e:Exception) { }
```

or

```
    disposable = apiRepository.fetch()
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(
            { result -> try { doSomethingThatWillCrash() } catch(e:Exception) { } },
            { error -> showError(error.message }
        )
```

But that's ugly... Any recommendation?

Answer (score 1):

What about propagating your error into the `onError` block:

```kotlin
disposable = apiRepository.fetch()
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .doOnSuccess { doSomethingThatWillCrash() }
    .subscribe({ result ->
        // nothing to do now
    }, { error ->
        // handle all errors including one from fun `doSomethingThatWillCrash()`
        showError(error.message)
    })
```

Not sure if `apiRespository.fetch()` returns `Single`. If not, use proper Rx operator based on your return type like `.doOnNext()` for `Observable` etc.

Comment: Nice one.. Cool. I also found another way and share as another answer.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to register the `setErrorHandler` as below

```
    RxJavaPlugins.setErrorHandler { error -> showError(error.message) }

    disposable = apiRepository.fetch()
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(
            { result -> doSomethingThatWillCrash() },
            { error -> showError(error.message) }
        )
```

As per shared by [InterruptedException not caught on RxJava onError callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57646184/3286489)